# Problem In Making Circular Play Button For Music App

Tags: android, user-interface, button, audio-player

Hello there I am a new Android developer and facing a simple problem in my button design.I was trying to make a music app and I want to add a play/pause button in my app so I added this button from material design android :- [image: FIRST]

**You can see in this image that there is not any circular background in this button only simple button it is. My question is I want to make a Play or Pause button with red Circular Background
like this :-**

[image: SECONDIMAGE]

**In the above second image there is a black background but I want to add red background instead , I can do this with downloading images from google but I want to make this image using vector code android.**

I hope you understand the question. The main point is I want to add
red background in my Play/Pause button using code.

So please reply me if you have any answer regarding this.

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click on `res -> New -> Vector Asset`

[image]

2. Click on `Clip Art` icon

[image]

3. Search for and select play icon and click on `OK`

[image]

4. Click on color code and change it to red color (FF0000) and click on `Next`

[image]

5. Click on `Finish` and it will generate play vector icon in your drawable folder

[image]

Similarly, you can also generate pause icon by searching for pause in step 3.